# Мощность передатчика при передачи данных в сетях LTE

Tags: android

Возможно ли узнать мощность передатчика при передачи данных в uplink, в сетях LTE? Где может находится эта информация в телефоне?

Comment: я думаю, что нельзя программно узнать. Можете попробовать выяснить, какой передатчик стоит в конкретном устройстве, и посмотреть спецификацию этого передатчика

Comment: Дело в том, что мощность передатчика - это не статическая мощность. Она меняется в зависимости от расстояния от базовой станции.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вопрос задан не совсем корректно. По принятой терминологии доунлинк это сигнал от передатчика базовой станции до телефона абонента, а аплинк это обратный сигнал от телефона (и это тоже передатчик) к базовой станции. Излучаемая мощность передатчика телефона доступна как через сам телефон (обычно в меню настройки), так и через специальные программы. Мощность передатчика базовой станции абоненту недоступна.